# how to allow an access even if the document field is not available in firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

so I add a new field in my user document called `numberOfFollowers`, so the brand new user will have this field but, old user doesn't has this `numberOfFollowers` field.

in security rules I want to set that the `numberOfFollowers` should be a number. and if old user does not have this field then it still allowed to update their document.

so I set the security rules like this

```
match /users/{userID} {

      allow update: if isValidUserStructure(request.resource.data)

    }

  function isValidUserStructure(user) {
        return (user.numberOfFollowers is number || user.numberOfFollowers == null)
             && user.banned is bool
             && user.contactNumber is string
             && user.createdAt is timestamp
             && user.domicile is string
             && user.email is string
  }
```

but the access is always denied for old user that doesn't has this field because of this line `(user.numberOfFollowers is number || user.numberOfFollowers == null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a field is NOT present on some document, you should check the data object, which is a [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) type object, using the documented `in` operation that checks for presence of a key:

```
function isFieldPresent(data, fieldName) {
    return fieldName in data;
}
```

You can then choose what to do in this case.

Since null is a valid field value in Firestore, checking for null as you're doing now is definitely not the same thing as checking for non-existence.